# Problem with understanding Proof if two different subsequences have different limits then $(x_n)$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, limits

As the title says I have problem understanding this proof. It seems ti ne that the proof is only about subsequences and not the main sequence itself. The proof I am referring to is from [Two subsequences with different limits limplies **diverge**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545297/two-subsequences-with-different-limits-limplies-diverge) .

**Problem**

> Prove that if two subsequences of a sequence $\{a_n\}$ have different limits $a \ne b$, then $\{a_n\}$ diverges.

**Answer**

> Pick a value of $c$. We wish to show that the sequence does not converge to $c$. Now, either $b\neq c$ or $a\neq c$ (or both). Without loss of generality, assume $a\neq c$.

> Then let $ϵ=\frac{|a−c|}{2}$. Now let $N$ be any natural number.
>
> **(1)** Our task, now, is to find some $s>N$ so that $|c−x_s|\ge\epsilon$.
>
> **(2)** Since $\{x_{n_i}\}$ converges to $a$, let $s=n_i$, where $n_i$ is large enough so that $|a−x_{n_i}|<ϵ$ and $n_i\gt N$.
>
> **(3)** Then
> $$|c−a|=|c−x_s+x_s−a|≤|c−x_s|+|a−x_s|<|c−x_s|+ϵ=|c−x_s|+\frac{|c−a|}{2}$$
> Therefore,
> $$|c−x_s|>\frac{|c−a|}{2}=\epsilon$$

My understanding of the proof:

(1) This I understand. We want to show that $(x_n)$ diverges and this is the negation of the definition of limits of sequences of real numbers.

(2) Here $n_i$ is chosen such that it is large enough that $|a-x_{n_i}|<\epsilon$ but also $n_i>N$. I have troubles understanding why setting $s=n_i$.

(3) Here it is inferred from from $|a-x_{n_i}|<\epsilon$ that $|a-x_s|<\epsilon$ but $x_{n_i}$ and $x_s$ are members of two different sequences. Is it not possible that there is a $x_s$ such that  $|a-x_s|\geq\epsilon$ even if $s=n_i>N$? If $x_s$ are members of the subsequence I don't know how this proof makes sense.

Edit: I don't buy that $|a−x_s|<ϵ$ as it says in (3). Just because there is a $M∈\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n_i≥M$ then $|a−x_{n_i}|<ϵ$ we can't infer from $n_i>N$ and $s=n_i$ that $|a−x_s|<ϵ$. Why? Because it's two different sequences we are talking about. There may be a number in $(x_n)$ even if $s>N$ such that $|a−x_s|>ϵ$ but |$a−x_{n_i}|<ϵ$.

Here I outline the proof using the method above to hopefully clearly show what I have problem understanding.

Suppose we have the alternating sequence $(x_n)=(1,-1,1...)$ and the subsequence $x_{n_i}=(1,1,1,...)$.

**Start of proof that the sequence $(x_n)$ is divergent**

Let $c\neq 1$, $\epsilon=|c-1|/2$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. For any $\epsilon>0$ and $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $|x_{n_i}-1|<\epsilon$. Let $n_i=s>N$, then $|c-1|=|c-x_s+x_s-1|\leq |c-x_s|+|x_s-1|<|c-x_s|+\epsilon$. Right here for me the proof breaks down. We want the proof to be about the main sequence so $x_s$ here are members of $(x_n)$. So $x_s$ is either $1$ or $-1$ so $|x_s-1|=0$ or $|x_s-1|=2$ depending if $s$ is even or odd.

Edit 2: Does the proof above specifically show that the subsequence can't have two different limits and thus $(x_n)$ is divergent?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. You are now asking two questions in one post, which is against community guidelines on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Sorry but to me it is the same question just different methods.

Comment: It's two questions. One question is "how is this proof valid", the other question is "how is this other proof valid". Each question has a separate answer, and deserves a separate post. The two questions may be related, but their answers will be completely separate.

Comment: Yes but  if I understood how the first one is valid I would also understand the second one. It is the relation about the proofs on subsequences and main sequences that I'm asking about. Let me take a break I'll come back and explain this horrible thread.

Comment: If you understood the first one, exactly. But for now, let the second one go. Focus on the first one, and try to understand the first one. Once you do, you might also already understand the second one, and you won't even need a second question. Asking **both** of them at the same time just makes it extremely hard to answer your question, because your question has two sub-questions. Trust me: **focus on one question at a time**. And focus on concrete proofs, not some hard to grasp concepts.

Comment: @5xum Nice one, you said all that and then when coming to what I have a problem understanding you deleted everything. Anyway I have edited my post to clearly state what my problem is.

Comment: Why $s=n_i$.  It's just labels.  $n_i$ is chosen that $|a-x_{n_i}| < \epsilon$ using the subsequence that converges to $a$.  But we want to apply this index to the entire sequence.  We could call the value $n_i$ but that may have associations with the susequence.  So we call it $s$ because that is a more neutral name.  But that's just it.  It's only a name.

Comment: 3) "but xni and xs are members of two different sequences"  well, no.  $s = n_i$ so $x_{n_i} = x_s$ and $x_{n_i}$ is *one* element in the sequence that converges to $a$. But that's enough.  For any $N$ we will always find $n_i$ where $x_{n-i}$ is in subsequence of that converges to $a$, so that $x_{n_i}$ is too close to $a$ and therefore too far from $c$.  So we cant have any $N$ where *all* $m>N$ are close to $c$ as there will always be an $n_i$ so that $x_{n_i}$ is to close to $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be an easier proof.

Let $S= \{x_s\}$.  Let $A \subset S$ and $A= \{x_{m_i}\}\subset S$ and suppose $A$ converges to $a$.  Let $B\subset S$ and $B= \{x_{n_j}\}$ and suppose $B$ converges to $b \ne a$.

Let $\epsilon = \frac {b-a}4> 0$.

As $A$ converges to $a$, there will be a $K $ so that if $m_i > K$ we have $|a-x_{m_i}| < \epsilon$ and and $B$ converges to $b$, there is an $M$ so that if $n_j > M$ we have $|b-x_{n_j}|<\epsilon$

Claim:  The is no $c\in \mathbb R$ and no $N\in \mathbb N$ where $s > N$ will imply $|c-x_s| < \epsilon$.

Pf:  Pick any $c$ and any $N$.  Let $W = \max(K, M, N)$.

Now $A$ and $B$ are infinite subsequences of $S$.  So no matter how large $W$ we can always find a term $a_w \in A\subset S$ where $w > W\ge K$.  And we can always find a term $a_v \in B\subset S$ where $v> W \ge M$.

(*I think that might be the point you were missing.  As $A$ and $B$ are infinite, no matter how far you go in the parent sequence $S$, there will always be terms of $A$ and there will always be terms of $B$ further along.*)

(*And the heart of the argument we can't have the terms that are in $A$ heading toward $a$ and the terms that are in $B$ heading toward $b$ while somehow having* **all** *the terms heading toward $c$.  If they are* **all** *heading toward $c$ you cant have two sets of them heading in two* **different** *directions!*)

Since $w > K$ and $x_w \in A$,  we have $|a-x_w| < \epsilon$.  If $|c-x_w| < \epsilon$ we can show that $|a-c|< 2\epsilon$.  ($|a-c|=|a-x_w+x_w -c|< |a-x_w| +|x_w -c| < \epsilon + \epsilon = 2\epsilon$)

But we also have $v > W \ge M$ and $a_v \in B$, so we have $|b-x_w| < \epsilon$.  If $|c-a_v| < \epsilon$ we can show that $|b-c| < 2\epsilon$ (ditto).

So if $c$ is so that *both* $|c-a_w| < \epsilon$ and $|c-a_v| < \epsilon$ we will have that both $|a-c| < 2\epsilon$ and $|b-c| < 2\epsilon$ and therefore $|a-b|=|a-c +c-b|\le |a-c|+|c-b|< 2\epsilon + 2\epsilon= 4 \epsilon = |b-a|$.  Oops. That's impossible.

But as both $w, v > N$ and it is not possible so that *both* $|c-x_w| < \epsilon$ and $|c-x_w| < \epsilon$ and as $a_w\in A\subset S$ and $a_v\in B\subset S$ we have $x_w, x_v \in S$, it is not possible for *ALL* $s > N$ to imply $|c-x_s| < \epsilon$.

So it is not possible for there to be such an $N$ and $c$.

And if there is no such possible $c$ and $N$ we can not have $\lim x_n = c$.

======OLD POST BELOW (very long)

I think we may be getting confused by the notation of indexes and subindexes.  The thing is it isn't actually very important but lets clear it up.

We have a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, .......$  The indexes of the sequence are $1,2,3,...$ and the cover the whole natural numbers.

We have subsequence $a_{something}, a_{somethingelse}, a_{athirdthing}....$ were the terms are all from the big sequence but not all of them.  For example our subsequence *migh* be  $a_3, a_5, a_9, a_{13}, a_{52}, .....$.  We don't know which terms will or want be in the sequence.  But we do know the fall in order.  We can't have $a_3, a_5, a_9, a_{13}, a_{52}$ and then jump back to $a_7$ say.

Okay... so they way we reference this is to refer to the terms of the subsequence as $a_{n_1}, a_{n_2}, a_{n_3},....$ where $n_{k}< n_{k+1}$.  In our example where the subsequence is $a_3, a_5, a_9, a_{13}, a_{52}$ we are referring to the indexes as $n_1 =3, n_2=5, n_3 =9, n_4=13$, etc and our subsequence is just refered to but $a_{n_1}, a_{n_2}, a_{n_3}, a_{n_4},.....$

Phew!  This really isn't important but it will help.

Now we have two subsequence $a_{n_1},a_{n_2},....$ that converges to $a$ and another $a_{m_1}, a_{m_2},a_{m_3}.... $ that converges to $b \ne a$.

Now the proposal is we can't have the parent sequence converge to anything that is *not* $a$ or $b$ (and as *everything* is either not $a$ or not $b$ we can have the parent sequence converge to anything).

Okay?  Here we go...

=====

Let $c\ne a$ then $\epsilon =\frac{|c-a|}2$ (which is the midpoint of $c$ and $a$) then we can find any $N$ so that if $k > N$ we will always have $|a_k -c| < \epsilon$.

Now the *reason* we won't be able to is because we have a subsequence ${a_{n_i}}$ where there is an $M$ where for all the $i > M$ we will have $a_{n_i}$ get close to $a$ which means we *can't* have all the $a_n$ where $n >M$ get close to $c$ which is far away from $a$.

So here's what the proof does:  It says we want $N$, an arbitrary number, to be a "hurdle" for $a_n \to c$.  We are going to prove that is impossible.  We *have* $M$ which *is* a "hurdle" for the subsequence $a_{n_i} \to a$. [By "hurdle" I mean that for all $k > M$ we have $|a_{n_k} - a| < \epsilon$ and for all $s > N$ we have $|a_s - c| < \epsilon$.]

We want to find an $s$ where the hurdle for $|a_s-a| < \epsilon$ fails.

We do this by letting $i > M$ but letting $i$ be also large enough so that $n_i > N$.  (We can do this by noting that as $n_1, n_2,n_3, ....$ are a subset of $1,2,3,4$ we always have $n_i \ge i$ so we let $i> \max(M,N)$ we will have $n_i \ge i > \max(M,N)\ge N$....but that wasn't important.  As sequences go on forever we can always pick an index as far out as we need.)

So $n_i$ is a natural number.  $a_{n_i}$ is the $i$th term of the subsequence $a_{n_i}$.  And $n_i$ is a natural number.  And $a_{n_i}$ is the $n_i$th term of the parent sequence $a_k$.

And $a_{n_i}$ is a term far out enough in the subsequence that converges to $a$ so that $|a-a_{n_i}| < \epsilon$.  But $a_{n_i}$ is also a term of the parent sequence that is past the $n$th term.

Now the proof showed that if $|a-a_{n_i}| < \epsilon$ then $|c-a_{n_i}| > \epsilon$.

[because $|c−a|=|c−x_{n_i}+x_{n_i}−a|≤|c−x_{n_i}|+|a−x_{n_i}|<|c−x_{n_i}|+ϵ=|c−x_{n_i}|+\frac{|c−a|}{2}$ and therefore $|c−x_{n_i}|>\frac{|c−a|}{2}=\epsilon$]

That *means*.....

We can never find an $N$ where $n > N$ implies $|c-a_n| < \epsilon=\frac{|c−a|}{2}$ because for any $N$ we *try* we can always find an $n_i > N$ where $a_{n_i}$ is in the subsequence that converges to $a$ and where $|a-a_{n_i}| < \epislon$, and therefore $|c-a_{n_i}|> \epsilon$.

That's what the proof is saying.  Is it clearer now?

Your questions.

2. Here ni is chosen such that it is large enough that |a−xni|<ϵ but also ni>N. I have troubles understanding why setting s=ni.

Ans:  We wanted to find an $s$ so that $|c-a_s| > \epsilon$.  We showed we can find an $n_i > N$ where $|c-a_{n_i}| > \epsilon$.  SO we just assigned the value to $s$.

3)Here it is inferred from from |a−xni|<ϵ that |a−xs|<ϵ but xni and xs are members of two different sequences.

But $n_i = s$ and $a_{n_i}=a_s$ is a member of *both* sequences (but in different places in the sequences [but both are far enough that $a_{n_i}$ is past the hurdle for $|a-a_{n_i}|$ to be $< \epsilon$, and far enough that $n_i = s > N$])

3 cont) Is it not possible that there is a xs such that |a−xs|≥ϵ even if s=ni>N?

Of course.  But we need to find an $N$ where *ALL* the values are such that $|c-x_s| < \epsilon$.  We can't find an $N$ where *ALL* $s > N$ make that true, because there will *always* be *some* of then $n_i < N$ will be so that $|a-a_{n_i}| < \epsilon$ and therefore $|c-a_{n_i}| \ge \epsilon$.  We can find *some* $s$ that work, but it will *never* be the case that *ALL* $s > N$ work.

EDIT: Why? Because it's two different sequences we are talking about.

But the subsequence is *contained* in the master sequence.  No matter how far we go in the master sequence there will always be terms of the *sub*sequence further along (because both are infinite).  We can never find a point in the master where we will *never* have any more of the subsequence, and worse yet, we will always reach a point where all the further terms of the subsequence (which *must* occur) will all have to be too close to $a$.

Your question: Edit 2: Does the proof above specifically show that the subsequence can't have two different limits and thus (xn) is divergent?

Well, I don't understand your proof but if you have shown $|x_s -1| = 0$ if $s$ is odd$ and $|x_s-1| = 2$ if $s$ is even then, absolutely, this can never converge!

Comment: nice text im gonna go through it later