# What is the limit of $\sin(n^2\pi/2)$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$?

Tags: calculus

I said it does not exist because $\sin(n^2\pi/2)$ oscillates back and forth as $n$ approaches infinity. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, although whether or not that's rigorous enough depends on what class it's for

Comment: **Hint :** Consider the case $n$ even and the case $n$ odd.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe is correct, but maybe you are thinking too much for this very question and really want an answer for $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x^2\pi/2)$? With constrictions on $x$ as part of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, we can construct two subsequences with two different limits. Let $s_n:=\sin(n^2 \pi/2)$, $a_n:=s_{2n}$, $b_{n}:=s_{2n+1}$ for all $n\geq 0$. Then $a_n=0$ for all $n$, and hence $a_n\to0$, while $b_n=1$ for all $n$, and hence $b_n\to1$. Therefore, there are two convergent subsequences with different limit, and thus the limit for $s_n$ does not exist.

On the why the limit does not exist, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429991/if-a-sequence-has-two-convergent-subsequences-with-different-limits-then-it-doe).